# How to plot daily plots from yearly time series

Tags: python

I have hourly ozone data over a multi year period in a pandas dataframe. I need to create plots of the ozone data for every day of the year (i.e. 365 plots for the year). The time series is in the following format:

```
    time_lt
3   1980-04-24 17:00:00
4   1980-04-24 18:00:00
5   1980-04-24 19:00:00
6   1980-04-24 20:00:00
7   1980-04-24 21:00:00
8   1980-04-24 22:00:00
9   1980-04-24 23:00:00
10  1980-04-25 00:00:00
11  1980-04-25 01:00:00
12  1980-04-25 02:00:00
13  1980-04-25 03:00:00
14  1980-04-25 04:00:00
```

How would I group the data by every day in order to plot each? what is the most efficient way of coding this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Find comments inline

```py
df['time_lt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_lt'])

# you can extract day, month, year
df['day'] = df['time_lt'].dt.day
df['month'] = df['time_lt'].dt.month
df['year'] = df['time_lt'].dt.year

#then use groupby
grouped = df.groupby(['day', 'month', 'year'])

# now you can plot individual groups
```

Comment: What is the grouped variable do? Never seen that type of variable before. And then how would I go about plotting each day and the corresponding ozone data?

Comment: `for name,group in grouped:
   print(name, group)` group is a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can group on the fly:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
"""id   time_lt
3   1980-04-24 17:00:00
4   1980-04-24 18:00:00
5   1980-04-24 19:00:00
6   1980-04-24 20:00:00
7   1980-04-24 21:00:00
8   1980-04-24 22:00:00
9   1980-04-24 23:00:00
10  1980-04-25 00:00:00
11  1980-04-25 01:00:00
12  1980-04-25 02:00:00
13  1980-04-25 03:00:00
14  1980-04-25 04:00:00"""), sep=" \s+")

df['time_lt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_lt'])
>>> df.groupby(df.time_lt.dt.floor('1D')).count()
            id  time_lt
time_lt
1980-04-24   7        7
1980-04-25   5        5
```

In theory, you can write a plotting function and `apply` it directly to the `groupby` result. But then it will be harder to control it. Since plotting itself will still be slowest operation in this chain, you can safely do simple iteration over dates.